# Passing value from ajax to php variable in same page

Tags: php, jquery

Since 3days i am trying my best to get the solution from Ajax & PHP, i tried all tutorial but i am unable to get the solution, i am new to Ajax,Jquery but my question is really simple to you all.

i have developed website using jquery & PHP, i have created menu using HTML (ul, li) so what i want is, if i click on menu item ajax should send value to php variable and then execute php function, but all this should happen in same page,..

Please help me to resolve the issues.

So far, I have tried the following:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var val = "Hi";
        $.ajax ({
            url: "oldindex.php",
            data: val,
            success: function() {
                alert("Hi, testing");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP and HTML:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="submit">
<form name="numbers" id="numbers">
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
</form>

<div id="number_filters">
    <a href="abc">1</a>
    <a href="def">2</a>
    <a href="ghi">3</a>
</div>
```

so if i click on href, i should get the value to php variable it should happen in same page only

Comment: What do You mean by "the same page"?

Comment: for example if i writing above script in gallery.php, then ajax should pass value to gallery.php only, it should happen in self page only...

Comment: where is your php function which process the ajax request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`index.php` page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var val = "Hi";
        $.ajax ({
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { val : val },
            success: function( result ) {
                alert("Hi, testing");
                alert( result );
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<input type="submit" id="btn" value="submit">
<form name="numbers" id="numbers">
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
</form>

<div id="number_filters">
    <a href="abc">1</a>
    <a href="def">2</a>
    <a href="ghi">3</a>
</div>
```

`ajax.php` page

```
<?php
echo ( $_GET['val'] );
```

Comment: you can get the value using `$_GET['val']` in your `"oldindex.php"` page.

Comment: <?php
   echo $_GET['val'];
   ?>

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var val = "Hi";
        $.ajax ({
            url: "test8.php",
            data: val,
            success: function() {
                
            }
        });
    });
      </script>

Comment: @user2454281 Did you change  `data: val` to `data : {val : val}`. I have checked locally and it is working fine.

Comment: no i just copied same thing from this post and tried, as i said you i am new to ajax and jquery so...

Comment: can you send me full working page so i can download and try it in local machine plz

Comment: @user2454281 Wait... I will send you.

Comment: @user2454281 Please approve my answer if you think this is useful.

Comment: so according to you, in same page i can pass value from ajax to php variable.. right,, can you also give me sample code how can i pass value to otherphp file and get output value from php file and show details in main page

Comment: Guys, above answer is not for same page. It;s using another page and question is about ajax response in same page. Here, same page means ajax code and ajax url are in same page.

Comment: Hi, see below is my website which i need code to resolve the issues  http://emsoftware.in/Royaltouchin/oldindex.php, please click on gallery tab, and when any one click on category i want to show images related to category plz help me...

Answer (score 4):

Let's see:

1- If you are doing a AJAX call, your page won't be refreshed. So if you try to send variables to the same page that makes the AJAX call it won't work, here's why. When you are able to see the page and execute the AJAX call, the code is already on the client side (your web explorer), there no PHP will be seen or executed (PHP is executed on the server only), so it's imposible for the same page to capture and process variables you pass to it using AJAX (since AJAX WON'T refresh the page, that's the point of AJAX).

2- If you are using AJAX you don't have to call to the same page. Call to another PHP, it will make the server side work for you, then return the result:

```
success: function(data) {
   alert("Hi, server returned this: "+data);
}
```

3- When you pass variables using AJAX you have to assign the variable a name, so it can be read in the PHP side:

```
data: {value: val},
```

4- For what you have in your question, you don't start the AJAX call clicking a href, you have the AJAX function linked to a `input type=submit`, it also is outside a form.. so let's do this better:

```
<button id="btn">submit</button>
```

Comment: Hi, can you give me sample code so i can try plz, i am really new to ajax and jquery..

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution as given sample code:

```
<?php if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    echo $_GET['q'];
    exit;
} ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){    
        $("#btn").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var val = "Hi";
            $.ajax ({
                url: "test8.php",
                // wrong query. you are not passing key , so here q is key
                data: 'q=' + val,
                success: function(returnResponseData) {
                alert('Ajax return data is: ' + returnResponseData);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="numbers" id="numbers">    
        <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
        <input type="submit" name='button' id="btn" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```